# Метод Обьект может быть Функция? что такое Array?

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, jsx, ecmascript

Недавно столкнулсья с конструкцией Array.Ни где не смог найти документацию про него.То есть документация есть конечно но в нем не описывается Array один к нему всегда привязяны какие то прототипы обьекты функции и тогда далее.

> Обяснитье мне что делает **Array** в примере внизу где используется после
>   **spread** оператора и почему не где нету обяснений Array если есть хотель
>   бы увидеть ссылку

```
const transformedIngredients = Object.keys(props.ingredients).map( //  из метод Object.key возвращает массив который из свойст обьекта  присваивается переменной transformedI
        igKey => { //метод map возвращает новый массив который будет состоять из результатов вызова callback(item, i, arr) для каждого элемента arr.
            return [...Array(props.Ingredients[igKey])].map((_, i) => {//вот тут что за метод Array 
                return <Ingredients key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />;
         });
 });
```

Comment: Этот код  `return [...Array(props.Ingredients[igKey])].map((_, i)` просто издевательство.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин почему?

Comment: потому что конструкция некрасивая, как будто человек пытается почесать ухо тянувшись рукой через ногу.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин а как можно реализовать алтернативу ?

Comment: ну на самом деле в реакте много такого, он подобный синтаксис поощряет, лично мой выбор был уйти с реакта вообще, никому свой выбор не навязываю.

Comment: можно обычным циклом сделать, ну или сделать отдельную функцию хелпер если такое много где используется.

Comment: ну я не говорю что разработчик конкретно неправ, просто выглядит не очень красиво... красота и понятность кода, лёгкая читаемость это очень важно.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин я не мастер реакта я просто учусь ну вот такие конструкции меня тоже путает.

Comment: мне Vue.js нравится, красивый синтаксис, таких конструкций нет как в том коде что выше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://learn.javascript.ru/array#new-array

> создаёт массив из данных элементов, но если у него один аргумент-число  Array(число), то он создает массив без элементов, но с заданной длиной

есть `String()` есть `new String()`

js позволяет в одной функции реализовать сразу два поведения
таким образом одна и та же функция может быть и конструктором (new,this) и просто функцией (return)

ах да! по поводу `String()`, на сегодняшний день рекомендуется использование именно так, без `new`

```js
let a = 'z'
let b = new String('z')
let c = String('z')

console.log(a===b)//false
console.log(b===c)//false
console.log(c===a)//true
```

Comment: но там везде используется new Array.

Comment: @Spectr, есть `String()` есть `new String()` вам интересно нужно ли писать нью или как реализовано что можно так а можно эдак

Comment: аа все понятно добавьте к вашему ответу  и эту комментарию и я приму его.Спасибо за то что обяснили